# Cookie is undefined after login until page refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have a simple login system in my react application that works like this:

1. User logs in
2. Create a cookie with the jwt sent by the server
3. Set the global user state to the user's data from the server ( Using context API )
4. Navigate to the index page

Here's the code for it:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

    const { setData } = useUserData();

    const handleLogin = async (data: FormValues) => {
        try {
            const res = await normalFetch.post("/auth/login", data);
            cookies.set("sg-auth-token", res.data.token);
            setData(res.data.user);
            toast.success("Successfully logged in.");
            navigate("/");
        } catch (error: any) {
            isAxiosError(error) && toast.error(error.response?.data?.message);
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

I also have a hook that retrieves the token and returns it so I can use it later on everywhere.
The only problem is that whenever I login, the token is undefined and the only way to fix this is by refreshing the page.

Comment: How you retrieve token in other component?

Comment: @Harshnahta I have a hook that gets it for me, then i use that hook wherever i want, but i tried using cookies.get instead of that hook and the result was the same